# Group Time-series / Time-Stamps by day

Tags: r, group-by, time-series, timestamp

My data is a time series ordered in a table. One column of the table contains the date of data collection. The following table can serve as an example:

| Timestamp | Data | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | Data A | 1.0 |
| 2020-01-01 | Data B | 0.5 |
| ... | Data A | ... |
| ... | Data B | ... |
| 2020-01-31 | Data A | 1.4 |
| 2020-01-31 | Data B | 1.4 |
| ... | Data A | ... |
| ... | Data B | ... |
| 2020-12-31 | Data A | 0.2 |
| 2020-12-31 | Data B | 1.8 |

Since my evaluation must take place on a monthly level, I have already combined the individual days and output the average as a monthly value.

Since the corresponding data is collected from mid-month (15.) to mid-month (14.), I was wondering if there is a simple way in R to group the existing data accordingly? In addition, it would also be interesting to consider only sections of the time series, such as the 02nd to the 14th of each month?

Edit:

I would like to assign the individual days to corresponding months. Example for the first question: December 15 - January 14 corresponds to January.
Example for the second question: 02 January - 14 January corresponds to January

Does this make it clearer?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided an example of your desired output as it's not entirely clear. Are you trying to calculate the average value for each month?

Comment: Don’t use dashed entries unless that is precisely what is in the input file. If it is in the file as dashes then you will need to accept that they will become NA in a numeric or Date-classed column.

Comment: Please provide a complete reproducible example and show the corresponding expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).